# Why is MSMQ generating a high amount of LDAP traffic?

Tags: .net, ldap, msmq

Context:

- Using the standard .Net classes/layer over Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ).
- Instantiating MessageQueue objects for receiving and sending messages and I believe some LDAP is involved in resolving the queue paths upon creation of a MessageQueue (depending on the path format).
- Observing very high LDAP traffic when sending and receiving messages despite re-using the MessageQueue objects.
- Using a mix of private and public queues.

I'm not sure at this time if the LDAP traffic is occurring on the send and/or receive of messages, or if it is related to public and/or private queues (I would assume public queues, but not 100% sure).

Thanks.

Comment: Public queues require Active Directory (LDAP) authentication, private queues do not

Comment: @DaveRead That doesn't sound right. A public queue is the same as a private queue except it is published in AD. The permissions on either type of queue can be exactly the same.

Comment: @Locster So what path format are you using?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell with a private queue you can connect directly to the queue by IP / TCP port without having to authenticate with AD / LDAP

Comment: Turns out I did have a loop that was creating a MessageQueue object for each send of a message. Resolving this solved the problem. Regarding the suggestion that access to public queues requires authorisation and thus LDAP queries - I don't see a large/problematic amount of LDAP traffic posting to a public queue but there might be some smaller amount of traffic going on.

Comment: @DaveRead Exactly the same for public queues. If I use Direct formatnames, there is zero difference between sending to private and public queues.